# SonarQube Component Coverage details with JUnitTest reports: How to avoid resource not found warning?

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, sonarqube

I'm pretty new to sonar but unfortunately I wasn't able to find any information in the net the last to days which could help me to solve my problem.

I'm running a SonarRunner on a Jenkins server and I'm trying to insert jUnit reports in order to see some content in the Coverage tab of the project on SonarQube.

The problem seems to be in loading the created jUnit report since the error message is pointing out to the junit framework:

```
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.3
13:39:28.405 INFO  - Load global repositories
13:39:28.608 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=203ms
13:39:28.639 INFO  - User cache: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.sonar\cache
13:39:28.890 INFO  - Load plugins index
13:39:28.890 INFO  - Load plugins index (done) | time=0ms
13:39:29.202 INFO  - Process project properties
13:39:29.249 INFO  - Load project repositories
13:39:29.339 INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=90ms
13:39:29.339 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
13:39:29.444 INFO  - Load quality profiles
13:39:29.516 INFO  - Load quality profiles (done) | time=72ms
13:39:29.519 INFO  - Load active rules
13:39:29.766 INFO  - Load active rules (done) | time=247ms
13:39:29.771 WARN  - SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
13:39:29.771 INFO  - Publish mode
13:39:29.771 INFO  - -------------  Scan DatensatzManager
13:39:29.834 INFO  - Load server rules
13:39:29.879 INFO  - Load server rules (done) | time=45ms
13:39:29.911 INFO  - Base dir: D:\SonarTest\P2209-DatensatzManager\03-Umsetzung\06-Src
13:39:29.911 INFO  - Working dir: D:\SonarTest\P2209-DatensatzManager\03-Umsetzung\06-Src\.sonar
13:39:29.911 INFO  - Source paths: src
13:39:29.911 INFO  - Test paths: test/com/carmeq/dia/dsm
13:39:29.911 INFO  - Source encoding: windows-1252, default locale: de_DE
13:39:29.911 INFO  - Index files
13:39:30.051 INFO  - 162 files indexed
13:39:30.051 INFO  - Quality profile for java: Sonar way
13:39:30.067 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor
13:39:30.257 INFO  - Configured Java source version: none
13:39:30.459 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan...
13:39:30.459 INFO  - 144 source files to be analyzed
13:39:40.551 INFO  - 99/144 files analyzed, current file: D:\SonarTest\P2209-DatensatzManager\03-Umsetzung\06-Src\src\com\carmeq\dia\dsm\core\util\RawDatasetImportExport.java
13:39:50.558 INFO  - 138/144 files analyzed, current file: D:\SonarTest\P2209-DatensatzManager\03-Umsetzung\06-Src\src\com\carmeq\dia\dsm\template_editor\logic\GUIActions.java
13:39:51.303 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan done: 20844 ms
13:39:51.303 INFO  - 144/144 source files have been analyzed
13:39:51.303 WARN  - Java bytecode has not been made available to the analyzer. The org.sonar.java.bytecode.visitor.DependenciesVisitor@1f6e340, org.sonar.java.checks.UnusedPrivateMethodCheck@1f9344b are disabled.
13:39:51.303 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan...
13:39:51.303 INFO  - 18 source files to be analyzed
13:39:51.702 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan done: 399 ms
13:39:51.702 INFO  - 18/18 source files have been analyzed
13:39:51.702 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=21635ms
13:39:51.702 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
13:39:51.718 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=16ms
13:39:51.718 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
13:39:51.718 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=0ms
13:39:51.718 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor
13:39:51.718 INFO  - parsing D:\SonarTest\P2209-DatensatzManager\03-Umsetzung\06-Src\report
13:39:51.792 WARN  - Resource not found: junit.framework.TestSuite
13:39:51.795 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=77ms
13:39:51.795 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
13:39:51.795 INFO  - No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
13:39:51.795 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
13:39:51.795 INFO  - Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
13:39:51.798 INFO  - Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=3ms
13:39:51.798 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
13:39:51.798 INFO  - JavaCpdEngine is used for java
13:39:52.234 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=436ms
13:39:52.602 INFO  - Analysis report generated in 352ms, dir size=3 MB
13:39:52.986 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 384ms, zip size=1 MB
13:39:53.102 INFO  - Analysis report uploaded in 116ms
13:39:53.102 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/my:project
13:39:53.102 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
13:39:53.102 INFO  - More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AVLvPnH_lmKETL1ow_XQ
INFO:      ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 25.530s
Final Memory: 6M/134M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I absolutely don't know why Sonar is searching for the junit.framework.TestSuite. Is there anyone who can help me to solve this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that surefire sensor is about execution of unit tests NOT coverage.

To get coverage displayed, you need to provide a coverage report that you can generate using JaCoCo (recommended way and included in sonar java plugin) or using cobertura (need to install the dedicated plugin for SonarQube).

The surefire sensor will only get you information about the execution of tests.

Comment: I already got these reports. You can see that they are parsed. 

    13:39:51.718 INFO  - parsing D:\SonarTest\P2209-DatensatzManager\03-Umsetzung\06-Src\report
    13:39:51.792 WARN  - Resource not found: junit.framework.TestSuite

But I guess the error occurs while parsing them.

Comment: There is no error parsing them and those reports are reports about unit tests execution, not coverage. For coverage reports you will need a dedicated tool like JaCoCo.

Comment: I finally found out what you mean :) I created JaCoCo .exec files and now the coverage is shown in the coverage tab. But in the console output the warning with the TestSuite framework of JUnit is still remaining. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: The warning is due to something in your surefire report, nothing to worry about, but you can maybe open another question or ask about it on sonarqube@googlegroups.com (and share your surefire report).